# Two kubernetes deployments in the same namespace are not able to communicate

Tags: kubernetes

I'm deploying ELK stack (oss) to kubernetes cluster. Elasticsearch deployment and service starts correctly and API is reacheble. Kibana deployment starts but can't access elasticsearch:

From Kibana container logs:

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-05-08T22:49:26Z","tags":["error","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Request error, retrying\nHEAD http://elasticsearch:9200/ => getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND elasticsearch elasticsearch:9200"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-05-08T22:50:44Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-05-08T22:50:44Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
```

Both deployments are in the same namespace "observability". I also tried to reference elasticsearch container as **elasticsearch.observability.svc.cluster.local** but it's not working too.

What I'am doing wrong? How to reference elasticsearch container from kibana container?

More info:

> kubectl --context=19team-observability-admin-context -n observability get pods

```
NAME                            READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
elasticsearch-9d495b84f-j2297   1/1       Running   0          15s
kibana-65bc7f9c4-s9cv4          1/1       Running   0          15s
```

> kubectl --context=19team-observability-admin-context -n observability get service

```
NAME            TYPE       CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                         AGE
elasticsearch   NodePort   10.104.250.175   <none>        9200:30083/TCP,9300:30059/TCP   1m
kibana          NodePort   10.102.124.171   <none>        5601:30124/TCP                  1m
```

I start my containers with command

> kubectl --context=19team-observability-admin-context -n observability apply -f .\elasticsearch.yaml -f .\kibana.yaml

**elasticsearch.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  namespace: observability
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: "9200"
    port: 9200
    targetPort: 9200
  - name: "9300"
    port: 9300
    targetPort: 9300
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  namespace: observability
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: set-vm-max-map-count
        image: busybox
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command: ['sysctl', '-w', 'vm.max_map_count=262144']
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "512Mi"
            cpu: "1"
          limits:
            memory: "724Mi"
            cpu: "1"
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.7.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
        - containerPort: 9300
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "3Gi"
            cpu: "1"
          limits:
            memory: "3Gi"
            cpu: "1"
```

**kibana.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kibana
  namespace: observability
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: "5601"
    port: 5601
    targetPort: 5601
  selector:
    app: observability_platform_kibana
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: observability_platform_kibana
  name: kibana
  namespace: observability
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: observability_platform_kibana
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        # THIS IS WHERE WE SET CONNECTION BETWEEN KIBANA AND ELASTIC
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS
          value: http://elasticsearch:9200
        - name: SERVER_NAME
          value: kibana
        image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana-oss:6.7.1
        name: kibana
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5601
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "512Mi"
            cpu: "1"
          limits:
            memory: "724Mi"
            cpu: "1"
      restartPolicy: Always
```

**UPDATE 1**

As **gonzalesraul** proposed I've created second service for elastic with ClusterIP type:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
  name: elasticsearch-local
  namespace: observability
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 9200
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9200
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch
```

Service is created:

> kubectl --context=19team-observability-admin-context -n observability get service

```
NAME                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                         AGE
elasticsearch         NodePort    10.106.5.94     <none>        9200:31598/TCP,9300:32018/TCP   26s
elasticsearch-local   ClusterIP   10.101.178.13   <none>        9200/TCP                        26s
kibana                NodePort    10.99.73.118    <none>        5601:30004/TCP                  26s
```

And reference elastic as "http://elasticsearch-local:9200"

Unfortunately it does not work, in kibana container:

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-05-09T10:13:54Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch-local:9200/"}
```

Comment: What's the output? Any errors? Have you checked the logs and confirmed both services are running?

Comment: Output of what? Output for get pods, get services are in the question and they are in "running" state. Elasticserach API is accessible. I've checked Kibana's logs and it seems like "elasticsearch" host is unknown (see logs in question)

Comment: I mean that Elasticserach API is accessible via master node and 30083 port but not accessible inside Kibana container as elasticsearch:9200

Comment: ok. How do you configure kibana? All config is setting the variables ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS and SERVER_NAME?

Comment: Yes, that's all. ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS should reference to elasticsearch API address (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/docker.html). It works when I use docker-compose (https://gist.github.com/bocharovf/e19fa80f7b5f6b65db17249c91e79416)

Comment: I just tested it. The answer is below.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a `NodePort` service, instead use a `ClusterIP`. If you need to expose as a Nodeport your service, create a second service besides, for instance:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
  name: elasticsearch-local
  namespace: observability
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 9200
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9200
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch
```

Then update the kibana manifest to point to the ClusterIP service:

```
# ...
# THIS IS WHERE WE SET CONNECTION BETWEEN KIBANA AND ELASTIC
- name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS
  value: http://elasticsearch-local:9200
# ...
```

The nodePort services do not create a 'dns entry' (ex. elasticsearch.observability.svc.cluster.local) on kubernetes

Comment: Still not luck. Please see **UPDATE 1** for question

Comment: http://elasticsearch-local.observability.svc.cluster.local:9200 does not work too

Comment: Can you check if you container runtime (usually docker daemon) is using proxy ? if it does, check whether no_proxy has `.cluster.local`

Answer (score 0):

Edit the server name value in `kibana.yaml` and set it to `kibana:5601`.

I think if you don't do this, by default it is trying to go to port 80.

This is what looks like now `kibana.yaml`:

```
...
spec:
  containers:
  - env:
    - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS
      value: http://elasticsearch:9200
    - name: SERVER_NAME
      value: kibana:5601
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana-oss:6.7.1
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: kibana
 ...
```

And this is the output now:

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-05-09T10:37:16Z","tags":["status","plugin:console@6.7.1","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-05-09T10:37:16Z","tags":["status","plugin:interpreter@6.7.1","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-05-09T10:37:16Z","tags":["status","plugin:metrics@6.7.1","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-05-09T10:37:16Z","tags":["status","plugin:tile_map@6.7.1","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-05-09T10:37:16Z","tags":["status","plugin:timelion@6.7.1","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-05-09T10:37:16Z","tags":["status","plugin:elasticsearch@6.7.1","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from yellow to green - Ready","prevState":"yellow","prevMsg":"Waiting for Elasticsearch"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-05-09T10:37:17Z","tags":["listening","info"],"pid":1,"message":"Server running at http://0:5601"}
```

**UPDATE**

I just tested it on a bare metal cluster (bootstraped through kubeadm), and worked again.

This is the output:

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-05-09T11:09:59Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-05-09T11:10:01Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-05-09T11:10:01Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-05-09T11:10:04Z","tags":["status","plugin:elasticsearch@6.7.1","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from red to green - Ready","prevState":"red","prevMsg":"Unable to connect to Elasticsearch."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-05-09T11:10:04Z","tags":["info","migrations"],"pid":1,"message":"Creating index .kibana_1."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-05-09T11:10:06Z","tags":["info","migrations"],"pid":1,"message":"Pointing alias .kibana to .kibana_1."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-05-09T11:10:06Z","tags":["info","migrations"],"pid":1,"message":"Finished in 2417ms."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-05-09T11:10:06Z","tags":["listening","info"],"pid":1,"message":"Server running at http://0:5601"}
```

Note that it passed from "No Living Connections" to "Running". I am running the nodes on GCP. I had to open the firewalls for it to work. What's your environment?

Comment: Unfortunately error is the same. I add "value: kibana:5601" but it changes nothing. I also tried combine it with "elasticsearch:9200" and "elasticsearch-local:9200" - no luck. If it works on your environment and does not in mine - maybe it is a cluster DNS problem?

Comment: have you reverted the service type back to `ClusterIP`?

Comment: I currently have two services. One named "elasticsearch" with NodePort type and one named "elasticsearch-local" with ClusterIP

Comment: "What's your environment?". I am not an admin so I dont know. I have to talk with support/admin (takes time) or check it somehow by myself. If it helpful - kubectl version say: Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12", GitVersion:"v1.12.7+1.1.2.el7", GitCommit:"02dd7eef0970a31fb7bd6e3392a3d0e411870c59", GitTreeState:"archive", BuildDate:"2019-04-05T17:53:36Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: No. What I mean is where are your nodes running? If cloud provider, then probably you need to open the right ports. If on-prem, I would say the same, but different way. My point is that you might not have any issues with the configuration, but with the infrastructure below.

Comment: We have on-prem kubernetes deployment. I'll consult with support about that issue, tks